# Having trouble self joining a table with NULL values

Tags: sql, database, join, null

I have a single table that has the columns: personID, name, parentID1 and parentID2
Essentially I am looking to use this table to find a childs parent(s)
Not every child has both parents, so these values are NULL in the table. I have tried using self joins but it just is not working out for me.

**TABLE**

[image]

Here is what the table should look like:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ans how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ok will do in future. Sorry, first time posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use LEFT joins so each row is returned even if the there is no match in the right table

### List Parents for Each Person Even if 1 Parent is NULL

```
SELECT A.[name] AS Child
    ,B.[name] AS Parent1
    ,C.[name] AS Parent2
FROM YourTable AS A
LEFT JOIN YourTable AS B
    ON A.ParentID1 = B.PersonID
LEFT JOIN YourTable AS C
    ON A.ParentID2 = C.PersonID
WHERE A.ParentID1 IS NOT NULL
OR A.ParentID2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: With that query I am getting almost what I want, essentially the people that have both NULL for parent IDs are the parents and I dont want to display them. Could I just add a where at the end where it checks if both are null? Or how would that work?

Comment: Yes, just added a where clause to filter out to ensure at least 1 parentid has a value

Comment: Appreciate the help!